# Getting NaN values in neural network weight matrices

Tags: matlab, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

**I am trying to develop a feedforward NN in MATLAB. I have a dataset of 12 inputs and 1 output with 46998 samples. I have some NaN values in last rows of Matrix, because some inputs are accelerations & velocities which are 1 & 2 steps less respectively than displacements.

With this current data set I am getting w1_grad & w2_grad as NaN matrices. I tried to remove them using `Heave_dataset(isnan(Heave_dataset))=[];, but my dataset is getting converted into a column matrix of (1*610964).

can anyone help me with this ?

```
                                                                    %

%% Clear Variables, Close Current Figures, and Create Results Directory 

clc;
clear all;
close all;
mkdir('Results//'); %Directory for Storing Results

%% Configurations/Parameters

load 'Heave_dataset'

% Heave_dataset(isnan(Heave_dataset))=[];

nbrOfNeuronsInEachHiddenLayer = 24; 
nbrOfOutUnits = 1;
unipolarBipolarSelector = -1; %0 for Unipolar, -1 for Bipolar
learningRate = 0.08;
nbrOfEpochs_max = 50000;


%% Read Data

Input = Heave_dataset(:, 1:length(Heave_dataset(1,:))-1);
TargetClasses = Heave_dataset(:, length(Heave_dataset(1,:)));

%% Calculate Number of Input and Output NodesActivations

nbrOfInputNodes = length(Input(1,:)); %=Dimention of Any Input Samples
nbrOfLayers = 2 + length(nbrOfNeuronsInEachHiddenLayer);
nbrOfNodesPerLayer = [nbrOfInputNodes nbrOfNeuronsInEachHiddenLayer nbrOfOutUnits];


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Forward Pass %%%%%%%%%%%


%% Adding the Bias to Input layer

Input = [ones(length(Input(:,1)),1) Input];


%% Weights leading from input layer to hidden layer is w1

w1 = rand(nbrOfNeuronsInEachHiddenLayer,(nbrOfInputNodes+1));

%% Input & output of hidde layer

hiddenlayer_input = Input*w1';

hiddenlayer_output = -1 + 2./(1 + exp(-(hiddenlayer_input)));

%% Adding the Bias to hidden layer

hiddenlayer_output = [ones(length(hiddenlayer_output(:,1)),1) hiddenlayer_output];

%% Weights leading from input layer to hidden layer is w1

w2 = rand(nbrOfOutUnits,(nbrOfNeuronsInEachHiddenLayer+1));

%% Input & output of hidde layer

outerlayer_input = hiddenlayer_output*w2';

outerlayer_output = outerlayer_input;

%% Error Calculation

TotalError = 0.5*(TargetClasses-outerlayer_output).^2;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Backward Pass %%%%%%%%%%%

d3 = outerlayer_output - TargetClasses;

d2 = (d3*w2).*hiddenlayer_output.*(1-hiddenlayer_output);

d2 = d2(:,2:end);

D1 = d2' * Input;

D2 = d3' * hiddenlayer_output;

w1_grad = D1/46998 + learningRate*[zeros(size(w1,1),1) w1(:,2:end)]/46998;

w2_grad = D2/46998 + learningRate*[zeros(size(w2,1),1) w2(:,2:end)]/46998;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try vectorize your algorithm. First arrange your data in a 46998x12 matrix X.Add bias to X like X=[ones(46998,1 X]. Then the weights leading from input layer to first hidden layer must be arranged in a matrix W1 with dimensions numberofneuronsinfirsthiddenlayer(24)x(input + 1). Then X*W1' is what you feed in your neuron function (either is it sigmoid or whatever it is). The result (like sigmoid(X*W') is the output of neurons at hidden level 1. You add bias like before and multiply by weight matrix W2 (the weights that lead from hidden layer 1 to hidden layer 2) and so on. Hope this helps to get you started vectorizing your code at least for the feedforward part. The back-propagation part is a little trickier but luckily involves the same matrices.  
I will shortly recite the feedforward process so that we use same language talking about backpropagation.
There is the data called X.(dimensions 46998x12)
A1 = [ones(46998,1 X] is the input including bias. (46998x13)
Z2 = A1*W1' (W1 is the weight matrix that leads from input to hidden layer 1)
A2 = sigmoid(Z2);
A2 = [ones(m,1) A2]; adding bias again
Z3 = A2 * W2';
A3 = sigmoid(Z3);
Supposing you only have one hidden layer feedforward stops here. I'll start backwards now and you can generalize as appropriate.
d3 = A3 - Y; (Y must is part of your data, the actual values of the data with which you train your nn)
d2 = (d3 * W2).* A2 .* (1-A2); ( Sigmod function has a nice property that d(sigmoid(z))/dz = sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z)).)
d2 = d2(:,2:end);(You dont need the first column that corresponds in the bias)
D1 = d2' * A1;
D2 = d3' * A2;
W1_grad = D1/m + lambda*[zeros(size(W1,1),1) W1(:,2:end)]/m; (lamda is the earning rate, m is 46998)
W2_grad = D2/m + lambda*[zeros(size(W2,1),1) W2(:,2:end)]/m;
Everything must be in place now except for the vectorized cost function which have to be minimized. Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: @ CodeBlackj, Thank you very much for your help. I re-developed my code with vectors. But I am getting problem with back - propagation. (while calculating change in error w.r.t weights in outer layer,

Comment: I calculated in this way,

Comment: deltatotalerror_deltaweights_hiddentoouter = deltatotalerror_deltaOutouter(46998*1), deltaOutouter_deltainouter(46998*1), deltainouter_deltaweights_hiddentoouter(46998*25). I need a matrix of (25*1) to update the outer layer weights. I will edit the above code , could you please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post the code of the Activation_func_hidden? You use sigmoid or some other function?

Comment: i used sigmoid function

Comment: I used sigmoid in hidden layer and linear in outer layer.

Comment: @ CodeBlackj, Thank you very much for your help. I re-developed my code with your suggestion,but  I have some NaN values in last rows of Matrix, because some inputs are accelerations & velocities which are 1 & 2 steps less respectively. With this current data set I am getting w1_grad & w2_grad as NaN matrices. I tried to remove them using `Heave_dataset(isnan(Heave_dataset))=[];, but my dataset is getting converted into a column matrix of (1*610964). Could you please help me with this.

Comment: accelerations & velocities which are 1 & 2 steps less respectively than displacements.